# Spare part inventory management calculating safety stock for non-normally distributed demand?

Tags: normal-distribution

I have a spare part supply chain with 2 echelons in it. Please see attached image for reference.

[image: Spare part supply chain]

Currently there is a centralized spare part inventory where ROP is calculated based on outgoing demand. 
SS= normsinv(0.99) x Stdeviation x Sqrt(Lead time demand + review period).
Based on Shapiro-Wilk test and due to applicability of Central limit theorem the demand distribution at the centralized inventory point seems to fit with normal distribution.
Because of this, in theory I would be able to decrease the safety stock required by considering local DC and service centre demand variaiblity. However, this is where I face my biggest roadblock.

The spare part demand in service centres is not normally distributed, while the demand at the central location is. The z-score currently used does not seem to be reliable. This is further backed up by the fact that the spare part availability is between 85% to 87% at the service centres

I would like to propose an alternative method to ensure that the spare part availability is between 95 to 99% at the service centres. As such, I was looking into applying poisson probability distribution when calculating the requirements for ROP. However, I do not fully understand how to go about doing it.

Any help or advice on what is the best approach in this situation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To tackle that problem of non normality i used block bootstrapping for the sales time series. Having n simulations you can just make percentiles in the required amounts (eg 90% service level)